# How to insert a vertex into a QGraphicsPolygonItem?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

[image]
This polygon is drawn by the QGraphicsPolygonItem and the QGraphicsPathItem. Now I want to add vertices by clicking on the polygon edge with the mouse, but I added the code to add vertices, which causes the polygon to appear deformed.
please help me.
the code as follow.

```py
 class GripItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    editing = False
    circle = QPainterPath()
    circle.addEllipse(QRectF(-6, -6, 12, 12))
    square = QPainterPath()
    square.addRect(QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))
    def __init__(self, annotation_item, index):
        super(GripItem, self).__init__()
        self.m_annotation_item = annotation_item
        self.m_index = index
        self.mySignal = SignalManager()
        #self.editing = True
        self.setPath(GripItem.circle)
        self.setBrush(QColor("green"))
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor("green"), 2))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setZValue(11)
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setPath(GripItem.square)
        self.setBrush(QColor("red"))
        super(GripItem, self).hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setPath(GripItem.circle)
        self.setBrush(QColor("green"))
        super(GripItem, self).hoverLeaveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print("release")
        self.setSelected(False)
        super(GripItem, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.isEnabled():
            self.m_annotation_item.movePoint(self.m_index, value)
        return super(GripItem, self).itemChange(change, value)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            if self.editing:
                if self.m_annotation_item is not None:
                    print("parent")
                    #self.m_annotation_item.scene().removeItem(self)
                    it = self.m_annotation_item.m_items[self.m_index]
                    self.scene().removeItem(it)
                    del it
                    self.remove_point()
                    #del self.m_annotation_item.m_points[self.m_index]
                    self.m_annotation_item.setPolygon(QPolygonF(self.m_annotation_item.m_points))
        super(GripItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def remove_point(self):
        print(self.m_annotation_item.dict_points[self.m_index])
        self.m_annotation_item.m_points.clear()
        self.m_annotation_item.dict_points[self.m_index] = 0
        for key, value in self.m_annotation_item.dict_points.items():
            if  not isinstance(value, int):
                self.m_annotation_item.m_points.append(value)


class PolygonAnnotation(QGraphicsPolygonItem): 
    editing = False 

    def __init__(self, scene):
        super(PolygonAnnotation, self).__init__()
        self.parent_scene = scene
        self.m_points = []
        self.center_x = 0
        self.center_y = 0
        self.setZValue(10)
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor("green"), 2))
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.m_items = []
        self.dict_points = dict()

    def number_of_points(self):
        return len(self.m_items)

    def calculate_center(self, p):
        self.center_x += p.x()
        self.center_y += p.y()

    def addPoint(self, p):
        self.m_points.append(p)
        #print(len(self.dict_points))
        self.dict_points[len(self.dict_points)] = p        
        self.setPolygon(QPolygonF(self.m_points))
        item = GripItem(self, len(self.m_points)-1)
        self.scene().addItem(item)
        self.m_items.append(item)
        item.setPos(p)

    def removeLastPoint(self):
        if self.m_points:
            self.m_points.pop()
            self.setPolygon(QPolygonF(self.m_points))
            it = self.m_items.pop()
            if it is not None and self.scene() is not None:
                self.scene().removeItem(it)
                del it
        if self.editing and self.dict_points:
            last_key = list(self.dict_points.keys())[-1]
            self.dict_points.pop(last_key)

    def movePoint(self, i, p):
        if 0 <= i < len(self.m_points):
            self.m_points[i] = self.mapFromScene(p)
            self.setPolygon(QPolygonF(self.m_points))

    def move_item(self, index, pos):
        if 0 <= index < len(self.m_items):
            item = self.m_items[index]
            item.setEnabled(False)
            item.setPos(pos)
            item.setEnabled(True)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for i, point in enumerate(self.m_points):
                    self.move_item(i, self.mapToScene(point))
        return super(PolygonAnnotation, self).itemChange(change, value)


    def delete_polygon(self):
        for i in range(len(self.m_items)):
                it = self.m_items.pop()
                self.scene().removeItem(it)
        self.scene().removeItem(self)
        self.m_points.clear()
        del self

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
        super(PolygonAnnotation, self).hoverEnterEvent(event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.NoBrush))
        super(PolygonAnnotation, self).hoverLeaveEvent(event)

    def getQPointFromDict(self, dict):
        self.m_points.clear()
        for key, value in dict.items():
            if type(value) is not int:
                self.m_points.append(value)

    # insert a vertex to the polygon.
    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.parent_scene.current_instruction != Instructions.No_Instruction:
            self.parent_scene.current_instruction = Instructions.No_Instruction
            self.parent_scene.start_point = None

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            mouse_position = event.pos()
            index = self.isEdgeClick(mouse_position)
            if index != -1:
                # Add a vertex at the mouse click position
                self.insert_point(index, self.mapToScene(mouse_position))
        return super().mousePressEvent(event)
    
    def insert_point(self, index, p):
        self.m_points.insert(index, p)
        #print(len(self.dict_points))
        self.dict_points[len(self.dict_points)] = p        
        self.setPolygon(QPolygonF(self.m_points))
        item = GripItem(self, len(self.m_points)-1)
        self.scene().addItem(item)
        self.m_items.insert(index, item)
        item.setPos(p)

    def isEdgeClick(self, mouse_position):
        # Check if the mouse click is on the edge of the polygon
        if len(self.m_points) < 2:
            return False  # Need at least 2 points to have an edge

        polygon = QPolygonF(self.m_points)

        # Iterate through the edges of the polygon and check if the click is close to any edge
        for i in range(len(self.m_points)):
            p1 = polygon.at(i)
            p2 = polygon.at((i + 1) % len(self.m_points))

            # Calculate the distance from the point to the edge
            dist = distance_point_to_line(p1, p2, mouse_position)
                    
            # You can adjust this threshold as needed
            if dist < 1.0:
                return i+1

        return -1
```

This is a fail result.
[image]

please provide the right code, thanks!

Comment: Your approach seems more complex than it probably needs. First of all, since vertexes are part of the polygon, they should probably be *children* of the polygon item. Then, you're keeping track of points, point indexes and point items in three separate data structures, while they could (and probably should) be managed within a single structure: since points are the coordinates of items, you're fundamentally having duplicate coordinates, and since points are always in order (which is the order of the polygon), having a dictionary is pointless. These complications may be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `distance_point_to_line` computation (which you never provided, by the way) is valid, your have two problems:

- you are adding new grip items with the wrong index: the size of the polygon vertexes (`GripItem(self, len(self.m_points)-1)`), instead of their real index;
- you are not updating the indexes of the remaining vertexes (any existing vertex that is *after* the newly inserted one), so they will eventually return an invalid order when moving them; this is also a problem whenever you remove vertexes, because you're not updating the remaining ones;

Even if you fix the above, your implementation has conceptual flaws.

First of all, you're fundamentally storing vertex data in *four* different "places":

- the `m_points`;
- the `dict_points`;
- indirectly, with the `m_items` (which are placed at the same points);
- indirectly, the polygon points;

Then, since the grip items are clearly closely related to the polygon, they should not be "external" items, but *children* of the polygon.

By using a more appropriate hierarchy between those items allows better management of every aspect, avoiding unnecessary complications (such as your attempt to move grip items when the polygon is moved).

I decided to completely rewrite the whole implementation (based on some previous code of mine), because fixing the above points would have been even more complex.

The idea is that every grip item is always a child of the `PolygonAnnotation`, which completely manages their creation, removal and position change.

There is only *one* list of vertexes, which is the list of grip items, only used when they are moved or when new vertexes are added or any vertex is removed. This makes it simpler to find the index of a grip item whenever it's moved (or removed) and you don't need to manually update the indexes of each item every time the vertex count changes.

Note I changed the insertion/removal behavior by using keyboard modifiers (<kbd>Shift</kbd> to add, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for remove), since your code didn't explain about the "editing mode", nor what that `current_instruction` means (you should use `self.scene()`, by the way).

```py
class GripItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    _pen = QPen(QColor('green'), 2)
    circle = QPainterPath()
    circle.addEllipse(QRectF(-6, -6, 12, 12))
    circleBrush = QBrush(QColor('green'))
    square = QPainterPath()
    square.addRect(QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20))
    squareBrush = QBrush(QColor('red'))
    # keep the bounding rect consistent
    _boundingRect = (circle|square).boundingRect()

    def __init__(self, pos, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.poly = parent
        self.setPos(pos)

        self.setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
        )
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.setPen(self._pen)
        self._setHover(False)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            self.poly.gripMoved(self)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

    def _setHover(self, hover):
        if hover:
            self.setBrush(self.squareBrush)
            self.setPath(self.square)
        else:
            self.setBrush(self.circleBrush)
            self.setPath(self.circle)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._boundingRect

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
        self._setHover(True)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)
        self._setHover(False)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.button() == Qt.LeftButton
            and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier
        ):
            self.poly.removeGrip(self)
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)


class PolygonAnnotation(QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    _threshold = None
    _pen = QPen(QColor("green"), 2)
    normalBrush = QBrush(Qt.NoBrush)
    hoverBrush = QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100))
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            | QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
        )
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

        self.setPen(self._pen)

        self.gripItems = []

        if len(args) == 1:
            arg = args[0]
            if isinstance(arg, QPolygonF):
                self.setPolygon(arg)
            if isinstance(arg, (tuple, list)):
                args = arg
        if all(isinstance(p, QPointF) for p in args):
            self.setPolygon(QPolygonF(args))

    def threshold(self):
        if self._threshold is not None:
            return self._threshold
        return self.pen().width() or 1.

    def setThreshold(self, threshold):
        self._threshold = threshold

    def setPolygon(self, poly):
        if self.polygon() == poly:
            return
        if self.gripItems:
            scene = self.scene()
            while self.gripItems:
                grip = self.gripItems.pop()
                if scene:
                    scene.removeItem(grip)

        super().setPolygon(poly)
        for i, p in enumerate(poly):
            self.gripItems.append(GripItem(p, self))

    def addPoint(self, pos):
        self.insertPoint(len(self.gripItems), pos)

    def insertPoint(self, index, pos):
        poly = list(self.polygon())
        poly.insert(index, pos)
        self.gripItems.insert(index, GripItem(pos, self))
        # just call the base implementation, not the override, as all required
        # items are already in place
        super().setPolygon(QPolygonF(poly))

    def removePoint(self, index):
        if len(self.gripItems) <= 3:
            # a real polygon always has at least three vertexes,
            # otherwise it would be a line or a point
            return
        poly = list(self.polygon())
        poly.pop(index)
        grip = self.gripItems.pop(index)
        if self.scene():
            self.scene().removeItem(grip)
        # call the base implementation, as in insertPoint()
        super().setPolygon(QPolygonF(poly))

    def closestPointToPoly(self, pos):
        '''
            Get the position along the polygon sides that is the closest
            to the given point.
            Returns:
            - distance from the edge
            - QPointF within the polygon edge
            - insertion index
            If no closest point is found, distance and index are -1
        '''
        poly = self.polygon()
        points = list(poly)

        # iterate through pair of points, if the polygon is not "closed",
        # add the start to the end
        p1 = points.pop(0)
        if points[-1] != p1: # identical to QPolygonF.isClosed()
            points.append(p1)
        intersections = []
        for i, p2 in enumerate(points, 1):
            line = QLineF(p1, p2)
            inters = QPointF()
            # create a perpendicular line that starts at the given pos
            perp = QLineF.fromPolar(
                self.threshold(), line.angle() + 90).translated(pos)
            if line.intersects(perp, inters) != QLineF.BoundedIntersection:
                # no intersection, reverse the perpendicular line by 180°
                perp.setAngle(perp.angle() + 180)
                if line.intersects(perp, inters) != QLineF.BoundedIntersection:
                    # the pos is not within the line extent, ignore it
                    p1 = p2
                    continue
            # get the distance between the given pos and the found intersection
            # point, then add it, the intersection and the insertion index to
            # the intersection list
            intersections.append((
                QLineF(pos, inters).length(), inters, i))
            p1 = p2

        if intersections:
            # return the result with the shortest distance
            return sorted(intersections)[0]
        return -1, QPointF(), -1

    def gripMoved(self, grip):
        if grip in self.gripItems:
            poly = list(self.polygon())
            poly[self.gripItems.index(grip)] = grip.pos()
            super().setPolygon(QPolygonF(poly))

    def removeGrip(self, grip):
        if grip in self.gripItems:
            self.removePoint(self.gripItems.index(grip))

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
        self.setBrush(self.hoverBrush)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)
        self.setBrush(self.normalBrush)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.button() == Qt.LeftButton
            and event.modifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier
        ):
            dist, pos, index = self.closestPointToPoly(event.pos())
            if index >= 0 and dist <= self.threshold():
                self.insertPoint(index, pos)
                return
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

You can test the above with the following example code:

```py
def randomPoly(count=8, size=None):
    if count < 3:
        count = 3
    if isinstance(size, int):
        size = max(10, size)
    else:
        size = max(50, count * 20)
    maxDiff = size / 5
    path = QPainterPath()
    path.addEllipse(QRectF(0, 0, size, size))
    mid = 2 / count
    points = []
    for i in range(count):
        point = path.pointAtPercent((i / count + mid) % 1.)
        randiff = QPointF(
            uniform(-maxDiff, maxDiff), uniform(-maxDiff, maxDiff))
        points.append(point + randiff)
    return QPolygonF(points)


app = QApplication([])
scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.addItem(PolygonAnnotation(randomPoly(10, 200)))
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.resize(view.sizeHint() + QSize(250, 250))
view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
view.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but your code cannot implement increasing vertices. In the function closestPointToPoly, the code " line.intersects(perp, inters) " reports an error in my Pyqt5 environment. I changed it to "line.intersects(perp)", but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: @Paul_Dx the sentence "[...] reports an error" alone is not enough to allow us to understand the issue: **what** error you got? How can we help you if we don't know anything about the error?!

Comment: "XXX.intersects(perp, inters)" The api does not need to add "s". The correct way to write it is "XXX.intersect(perp, inters)". After my modification, I found that although the lines can be judged whether they intersect, when I use "shift+ left mouse button" to add vertices, the vertices and edges cannot be connected, and the polygon shape is confused.

Comment: You didn't explain if that is an actual *error* or a *warning* from the IDE (please *do* understand the difference between "error" and "warning"). In any case, it probably comes from the IDE or a debugging tool, and it's caused by the fact that `intersect` (without the final "s") has been declared obsolete since Qt 5.14, which changed the function name to `intersects`. About your last note, we need more context. Are you using my code *as it is*, or did you try to patch your code with mine? We can only tell you what's wrong about the code we know, if you did changes we need to be aware of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply! 
''' 
 if line.intersects(perp,inters) != QLineF.BoundedIntersection:
TypeError: intersects(self, l: QLineF): too many arguments
'''
The environment is
‘’‘
PyQt5                     5.15.9
pyqt5-plugins             5.15.9.2.3
PyQt5-Qt5                 5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                 12.12.1
PyQt5-stubs               5.15.6.0
pyqt5-tools               5.15.9.3.3
’‘’

Comment: I just changing it to "intersect " so that the code runs, but there's a problem with adding vertices.

Comment: @Paul_Dx I forgot how the PyQt signature changed with the introduction of `intercepts`. Try to apply [this change](//gist.github.com/MaurizioB/6548373e2978b37e7dcc605f16786aaa) within the `for` loop of `closestPointToPoly`. For future reference, always remember to explain *what* errors you get and the eventual difference with what you expect. Things like "it doesn't work" (without telling what happens), "it gives an error" (without showing the error) and so on are completely insufficient to understand the problem, and we cannot help in any way if we're just left with vague descriptions.

Comment: Thanks for your code, very good. I found my problem because I didn't use scene.setscenerect (), causing the scene to change as polygon changes.

Comment: The scene rect change only indirectly affected  your case, as it was a symptom of the real issue: as you can see from my example, I didn't need to use it in order to make it work. For future reference, please remember to provide a valid and complete [mre] in your question so that we won't have to write important portions on our own in order to test your code (it may not always be possible to understand it just by reading). Also, if my question solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray tick on its left.